# Writing a JavaFX project in Clojure

Tags: javafx, clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to understand how to properly setup JavaFX to work with a Clojure project. By reading various sources this is what I've come up with:

This is project.clj:

```
(defproject cljfx "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :resource-paths ["lib/jfxrt.jar"]
  :main ^:skip-aot cljfx.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

I don't know if I should use :resource-paths or add JavaFX to the classpath via the :dependencies vector...

This is core.clj:

I've basically translated to Clojure an example from this tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm

```
(ns cljfx.core
  (:gen-class
    :extends javafx.application.Application)
  (:import
    [javafx.application Application]
    [javafx.stage Stage]
    [javafx.scene Scene]
    [javafx.scene.control Button]
    [javafx.scene.layout StackPane]
    [javafx.event ActionEvent EventHandler]))


(defn -main [& args]
  (Application/launch cljfx.core args))

(defn button [text]
  (doto (Button.)
    (.setText (str "Say " text))
    (.setOnAction (proxy [EventHandler] []
                    (handle [event]
                      (println text))))))

(defn -start [primaryStage]
  (let [root (doto (StackPane.)
               (-> (.getChildren)
                   (.add (button "Hello World!"))))]
    (doto primaryStage
      (.setScene (Scene. root 300 250))
      (.show))))
```

This doesn't compile, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong... can you help me?

Here is the error:
http://pastebin.com/sYeK7MJd

Answer (score 2):

There may be other problems, but the root problem in the pastebin log is:

```
Caused by: clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (2) passed to: core/-start
```

When using gen-class and providing method implementations, every method needs to take the instance itself as the first parameter. The convention is to use "this":

```
(defn -start [this primaryStage]
```

Try that, and ensure that local instance method calls are applied to "this".

Comment: My bad, I didn't know that... but what do you mean with local instance methods? should -main have [this & args] instead of [& args]? I noticed that adding 'this' to -start makes it work, but I can't use it in -main in place of cljfx.core, can I?

Comment: No, main is a public static, like a global function. The namespace in which it lives is specified in the project.clj. start, otoh, is an Application instance method. It only has visibility to a particular instance, or copy, of the fields available in class Application. Anyway, the other place where this may be needed is in the handle method, it may need to be (handle [this event]... since what is being created is an instance of an EventHandler.

Comment: Hmm okay...what about project.clj? I still can't compile the project with 'lein run' (it throws a ClassNotFound exception with cljfx.core...weird) but it works if I build the uberjar and then run it as a java program...should I use :resource-paths or :dependencies to add javafx?

Comment: wiping the project and using :resource-paths works now, but I still have no idea why it didn't before

Comment: The problem was likely in the use of "aot" or ahead of time compilation. The crux of the issue is that there are two dependency resolution mechanisms- clojure namespaces and java classpaths. These can interact in strange and sometimes inappropriate ways that require delicate use of aot. Short version is- the ^skip-aot clause in project.clj is probably mistaken and should be removed (i think), and use "lein clean" in between major changes to clean up compiled classfiles generated from clojure sources.